# PHP Get everything after the domain name from a URL variable

Tags: php, url

I have a variable which stores the URL links
for example:

```
$link = "https://www.google.no/search?num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=example&oq=example"

$link = "http://www.example.com/forums/showthread.php?37dsf624-Get-everything-after-the-domain-name"
```

How do i extract the evrything which is after the domain name. for example i want from

```
$link = "https://www.google.no/search?num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=example&oq=example"
```

to extract

```
search?num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=example&oq=example
```

and from

```
$link = "http://www.example.com/forums/showthread.php?37dsf624-Get-everything-after-the-domain-name"
```

to extract

```
/forums/showthread.php?37dsf624-Get-everything-after-the-domain-name
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

look at the php function `parse_url` and `parse_str`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php

http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-str.php

you can extract everything from your url with this.

```
$link = "https://www.google.no/search?num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=example&oq=example";

$parsedUrl = parse_url($link);
parse_str($parsedUrl['query'], $parsedQuery);
print_r($parsedUrl);
print_r($parsedQuery);

Array
(
    [scheme] => https
    [host] => www.google.no
    [path] => /search
    [query] => num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=example&oq=example
)
Array
(
    [num] => 100
    [newwindow] => 1
    [safe] => off
    [site] => 
    [source] => hp
    [q] => example
    [oq] => example
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array[]= parse_url("https://www.google.no/search?num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=example&oq=example");

$reqstring="{$array[0]['path']}?{$array[0]['query']}";
echo $reqstring;
```